# Prevent Python from automatically "truncating" nested tuples

Tags: python, tuples

When I create a tuple where its only component is another tuple, such as ((1, 2)), python automatically changes it to simply (1, 2).

This is a really simple problem that I hope will at least have some possible workaround.

Comment: Try using `((1,2),)`.

Comment: `((1,2))` is not a singleton tuple containing another tuple  for the same reason `(1)` is not a singleton tuple containing an `int`, because the outer parentheses don't make a tuple, *the comma creates the tuple*. you need `((1,2),)` or even `(1,2),`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm not convinced this is a duplicate, even if the answer is related.

Comment: @MarkRansom it's the closest one, it's a common question of how to create a tuple with a single item, whether that item is an empty tuple or a 2 tuple doesn't seem that significant of a difference to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax isn't what you think it is.

This will create your nested tuple.

```
((1,2),)
```

Without the extra comma, you are just grouping the expression (think `(1+2)`).